# For CMake's "install" command, what can the COMPONENT argument do?

Tags: cmake

I don't know what the argument `COMPONENT` of the [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command means, and I don't understand the CMake documentation for this. What is it in more detail?

What would an example be?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can group installation targets into components, for example, "docs", "libs", "runtime", etc.

```
add_library(libone libone.c)
add_executable(one main1.c)
install(TARGETS libone one DESTINATION /somedir COMPONENT comp_one)

add_library(libtwo libtwo.c)
add_executable(two main2.c)
install(TARGETS libtwo two DESTINATION /somedir COMPONENT comp_two)
```

This makes it possible to run `cmake -DCOMPONENT=comp_one -P {your_build_dir}/cmake_install.cmake` to install only the `libone` library and the `one` executable. When you issue `make install` all components are installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the component will install together with the target in  one file or in the same directory with different file? In my opinion, i can install different targets like this :install(TARGETS myExe mySharedLib myStaticLib
            RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
            LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static). SO which is better

Comment: It's not about destination dirs, but which targets to install. For example, if you have 4 `install()` clauses, 2 with `COMPONENT a` and 2 with `COMPONENT b`. Then, if you run `make install` all 4 targets will be installed, but only 2 if you specify component name - "a" or "b".

Comment: Excuse me , what's a component. It still confused me, can you give me a test code. then i can run it. and see some difference

Comment: Thanks very much, and i clear now. you are very kind . I have another question. how to do in "make install" when i want to use function. is it only valid for cmake install by use cmake_install.camke

Comment: I've done some googling and it seems, that using `cmake` invocation is the only way to do it. But you can wrap it into target using `add_custom_target(TARGET install_one COMMAND ${CMAKE_PROGRAM} -DCOMPONENT=comp_one -P {CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake` and then use `make install_one`.

Comment: @arrowdodger Shouldn't the second `install` command specify `libtwo` and `two` as the targets?

Comment: The install each target command suggested above is broken in several spots, I suggest looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21853784/258418

Comment: This is also useful when creating CPack component style installers. Unfortunately, CPack is terribly documented, but the following two links are a start: [Component Install With CPack](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Component_Install_With_CPack) and [CPackComponent Variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackComponent.html)

Comment: If you defined multiple `COMPONENT`s and didn't specify one with `-DCOMPONENT`, the default would be to install all of the components, right?

Comment: There is a new feature `cmake --install <dir> --component <component>` since 3.15. Could you add this to your answer?

Comment: Can you run the component install with ninja aswell?

Answer (score -21):

There are three ways you can use the `install` command in CMake:

1. Install an executable

   ```
   INSTALL(TARGETS ExecutableTarget RUNTIME DESTINATION FOLDER_LOCATION)
   ```
2. Install a static library

   ```
   INSTALL(TARGETS StaticLibraryTarget ARCHIVE DESTINATION FOLDER_LOCATION)
   ```
3. Install dynamic library

   ```
   INSTALL(TARGETS SharedLibraryTarget LIBRARY DESTINATION FOLDER_LOCATION)
   ```

Comment: -1 because the question was about the meaning of the `COMPONENT` keyword. This answer demonstrates three *kinds* of targets which is an orthogonal concept.