# For CMake's “install”, what does the CONFIGURATIONS argument do?

Tags: cmake

I don't know what the `CONFIGURATIONS` argument of CMake's `install` command does. When I use `CONFIGURATIONS` with debug or release in installing files, no file gets installed. What happened?

Can someone explain it in more detail. It will be best if you give me some examples.

P.S. This is not the same as: [For CMake's "install" command, what can the COMPONENT argument do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190098/for-cmakes-install-command-what-can-the-component-argument-do)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3ainstall):

> The CONFIGURATIONS argument specifies a list of build configurations for which the install rule applies (Debug, Release, etc.).

So for example, consider the following CMakeListst.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Test)
add_executable(MyTest main.cc)
install(TARGETS MyTest DESTINATION bin CONFIGURATIONS Release)
```

This means that

```
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

will place the executable `MyTest` (or `MyTest.exe`) in `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin`, and

```
cmake --build . --target install --config Debug
```

won't install anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, with CMake 3.7.2, the CONFIGURATIONS option does not do anything. install will gladly install anything regardless of configuration :(