# syntax error near unexpected token `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX'

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to install gflags on openSuse 13.1.

CMake generated the install files OK, but when I try to run cmake_install.cmake, I get the above error.

The line it's referring to is:
`set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")`

Does anyone know what to do to get it to work, and why it has generated a seemingly unusable file?

Comment: That line looks OK. Chances are the error is on a previous line (*that we can't see*).

Comment: how and why do you run cmake_install.cmake? i don't think you should

Comment: @tamas.kenez There are cases where you may want to execute the `cmake_install.cmake` script directly. Mostly if you want to give parameters to it and therefor can't use the `INSTALL` make target generated by CMake (which calls it without/default parameters, see e.g. [For CMake's “install” command, what can the COMPONENT argument do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190098/for-cmakes-install-command-what-can-the-component-argument-do)).

Comment: @Biffen For me this looks like he is trying to run the `cmake_install.cmake` directly as a shell script. @Andy Stopford It's a CMake script file so you have to call `cmake -P cmake_install.cmake`. I just tested calling it directly from the shell with `./cmake_install.cmake` and get the same error you got. `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ...` is simply the first line that does not match the bash shell syntax.

Comment: Cheers everyone. I realised (late last night) that the build instructions I was following were highly misleading and I was indeed trying to run it as a shell script as Florian suggests. Just doing it the conventional way (make, make install, as below) worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, you just can't do this:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
```

To set the prefix and works as you expected..you need to defined **before** configuration begins, even before cmake begins:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local" ..
```

Also, you must know that typical build procedure is

```
cmake [..]
make
make install
```