# What dependencies does the built-in INSTALL target have?

Tags: cmake

CMake has a built-in `install` target, so that you can use `make install` if you're generating Makefiles, or build an `INSTALL` project in Visual Studio, etc.

The behavior of this target is defined by various `install()` commands in your CMake files, e.g. copying files or products of existing CMake targets to specific installation directories.

The `install()` command also allows you [to specify a **component**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190098/for-cmakes-install-command-what-can-the-component-argument-do). If you then call CMake specifying a component, then the `install` target will install *only* products associated with that particular component.

What I haven't found, though, is: **What targets does the `install` target depend on?**

- If one of my targets does not compile, will this cause `make install` to fail, even if that target doesn't produce anything for installation?
- If I'm building one specific component, and I've specified it in my original CMake call, will `make install` build *all* the targets in my source tree (but only install the one component)? Or will it build only the targets necessary for the installation of the specific component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on `all`.

You can control what's in this using `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, or remove the dependency by setting `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY`, but that doesn't replace it with specific targets, it just means make install does the installation without trying to build anything.

Here's the documentation from [`CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY.html)

> By default, the `install` target depends on the `all` target. This has the effect, that when `make install` is invoked or `INSTALL` is built, first the `all` target is built, then the installation starts. If `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY` is set to `TRUE`, this dependency is not created, so the installation process will start immediately, independent from whether the project has been completely built or not.

Answer (score 0):

`make install` *unconditionally* depends from `make all`.

That is, for install even single file you need to (successfully) complete `make all` stage.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I assume this applies also when I call CMake with a single component?

Comment: `Is this documented anywhere?` - It should ... but I cannot find the place. `I assume this applies also when I call CMake with a single component?` - yes, even installing single component requires whole project to be built (`make all`).