# Check if a CMake component exists

Tags: cmake

CMake's supports the expression `if(TARGET target-name)` to check if a target `target-name` actually exists. Is there anything similar to check if a CMake **component** with a given name exists? I couldn't find a `if(COMPONENT ...)`.

My use case is that we have CMake `install-foo` targets that install the target `foo` to `<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>`. We also have custom cmake functions to declare which components an `install-foo` target depends on, and when you "build" such an `install-foo` target, this will not just install the target itself, but also all components it depends on.

But we currently can't check whether the components that a target depends on actually exist (installing non-existent components will just fail silently). So a developer can easily rename a component without updating dependent targets, thereby breaking the installation dependency and resulting in an incomplete deployment.

Comment: What do you mean by "CMake component"? One, specified by *COMPONENT* option for `install` command? Or what?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, exactly.

Comment: Hm, but what do you mean by CMake component **existence**? In `install` command one just *refers* to some component, CMake code *doesn't define* a component. [This is opposite to the *targets*, which actually are *defined* in CMake code.] Also, components has a sence only in CPack. Could you elaborate your question with description, **why** do you need a component's check? What do you want to achive with it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev done.

Comment: I don't know how to check that from CMake script, but you may grep script `cmake_install.cmake`, which actually perform installation. Because this script may perform [per-component installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192877/3440745), it should contain all used components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using CPACK, list of components can be accessed after the include(CPack) line as below:

```
include(CPack)

message("DEBUG: List of all components => ${CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL}")
foreach(component ${CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL})
    message("INFO - component ${component}")
    message("INFO - ...is part of ${CPACK_COMPONENT_${component}_GROUP}")
endforeach(component)
```

List of files installed due to each component are available in the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` as:

```
install_manifest_<COMPONENT>.txt
```

If a component has NO files to install, the respective install_manifest file will be empty.

Using above set of information it should be possible to check if there are zombie components.